# Angular Conditional Class Based On Character Count

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, charactercount

How to conditionally apply a class based on the character count of the model?

E.g.:

`$scope.sample = 555;`

`<span ng-class="{ 'char3': sample.length == 3 }">{{ sample }}</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert sample to string and the check its length:

```
<span ng-class="{ char3: (sample + '').length == 3 }">{{ sample }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-class="(sample.length === 3) ? 'three':'notthree'">{{ sample }}</span>
```